# Can the state pattern be utilized to substitute types for state?

Tags: design-patterns, state-pattern

I just learned about the State Design Pattern and I am wondering if it is appropriate to apply the pattern to "types". The situation is this: We have several different types of data imports, and depending which type the user selects, depends on how we import data.

My understanding of the state pattern is that it eliminates the need to create complex switch and/or if statements utilizing state. Like my import, I would also like to eliminate switch/if statements depending on type. Unlike state though, once the file is imported I will never change it's state or type to another state or type.

I want to eliminate the below code so when we have to add more types it will be easier to maintain:

```
    //Prompt user to select import type then go below

     switch (typeof(MyDataToImportType))
        {
            case FileLatePaymentsImport:
                //Import File1
                break;
            case DatabaseReportsImport:
                //connect to db
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
```

Comment: A switch is usually a warning sign, and a switch on types probably a red flag. Not sure if the state pattern is all too relevant here though, instead I'd suggest looking into the different factory patterns or even dependency injection.

Comment: In any case, you'd need to provide us with a wee bit more code before we can help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you need is to use a Strategy rather than State.

You could remove that switch by having a `Dictionary<Type, IImportStrategy>` somewhere (or a `Factory` where you provide the type and return the proper strategy instance)

An example of the `IImportStrategy` interface could be

```
interface IImportStrategy {
    void Execute();
}
```

Then you would implement two implementations `class FileLatePaymentsImport IImportStrategy` and `class DatabaseReportsImport: IImportStrategy` where the specific logic would be included.

Answer (score 0):

The state pattern is more fit to react upon events, when the effect of those events depend on the current state.

So I totally agree with Sebastian Piu that the  Strategy pattern fits the purpose better in your case.